# Как сместились биты?

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, логические-выражения

Можете объяснить, как в этом задании получили последовательности 1, 2 и 3 справа в столбце в примере? Я не понимаю как их сместили[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из последовательности

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

извлекаются пары битов, находящихся на расстоянии 1,2,4 (и далее степени двойки, если Nd будет больше) друг от друга

Например, для последовательности 3

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
|_______|          01
  |_______|        00
    |_______|      10
      |_______|    11
```

Для понимания многомерности - пронумеруем "биты" (в кавычках - объекты из C, это могут быть буквы или другие обозначения), выпишем бинарное представление номера.

Пары k-й серии образуют "биты", у которых номера отличаются только одним k-м справа битом. В k-мерном кубе эти объекты располагаются на одном ребре куба.

```
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1
 0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
 000   001   010   011   100   101   110   111
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или для 1 не получается построить по такому правилу?

Comment: @Юрий Козлов Для 1 просто пары соседних - получается.

Comment: Наконец-то понял схему!! Для формирования следующего  слова берется первый  неиспользованный бит..... Тогда все сходится, для всех трех измерений.

Comment: @MBo спасибо большое!